# MYSQL LIKE OPERATOR WITH few characters match also

Tags: mysql

I have a database table with service categories. I want to do search based on the user selected input.
For example:

table - **service_categories**

```
id       | created_at          | updated_at           | service_category
1        | 2022-10-03 08:32:47 | 2022-10-03 08:32:47  | Roofing
2        | 2022-10-03 08:32:47 | 2022-10-03 08:32:47  | Roof Repair
3        | 2022-10-03 08:32:47 | 2022-10-03 08:32:47  | Roof Replacement
```

I want to get all three records if a user searched for **Roofing**.

I am trying:

```
SELECT * FROM service_categories WHERE 1 AND service_category LIKE '%Roofing%';
```

I also tried

```
SELECT * FROM service_categories WHERE 1 AND service_category LIKE 'Roofing%';
```

Also

```
SELECT * FROM service_categories WHERE 1 AND service_category LIKE '%Roofing';
```

The above query returns only the ones which has entire **Roofing** in the column. It does not return other columns with **Roof** in it.

Please can anyone guide me in the right direction?

PS: Sorry for wrong formatting.

Comment: Do you mean `LIKE 'Roof%'`?

Comment: Yes. But the user cannot input only Roof. The user will select a tag which will have full service category name, like `'Roofing'`

Comment: Suppose a user searched for `'Roofing'` so it should return all column which has Roof in its `service_category` column because you see `Roof` is common in all.

Comment: Then have a short category name assigned to each category and search on short one.

Comment: Mysql is database. If you need like that, check full-search engines like elasticsearch. Other option is create other "lookup" table which give list of possible related words, filll it yourself and use in join.

Comment: Will give that a try. Lookup table or another column with short category name.

Comment: Create a table `(user_input - search_pattern)` with rows similar to `('Roofing', 'Roof%')`, and use it as a source.